# display one image at a time from fetched data from json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I am a beginner in React trying to display one image at a time. Currently using this api https://salty-cove-08526.herokuapp.com/api/countries?format=json which sends 3 images at once. I am using axios to get the images and using map  `{this.state.countries.map(country => <img src={country.photo}/>)}`
but this command in div img-wrapper displays all the  3 at once plz hlep

reactjs

```
class form extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={
            answer:'',
            countries:[]
        }
        this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('https://salty-cove-08526.herokuapp.com/api/countries?format=json')
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({ countries:res.data});
                
            })
    }
       
    }
    render(){
 
        return (
            <div>
                <section className="login">
                    <div className="loginContainer">
                        <div className="heading">
                            Guess the countries
                        </div>
                        <div className="img-wrapper">
                            {this.state.countries.map(country => 
                                 <img src={country.photo}/>
                            )}
                        </div>
```

json

```
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "canada",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "sdsds",
    "capital": "sdsdsd",
    "hint_1": "sdsd",
    "hint_2": "sdsdsd"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "usa",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "ddc",
    "capital": "new york",
    "hint_1": "kuch bhi",
    "hint_2": "kljn;kj"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "china",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "ddfdf",
    "capital": "k k",
    "hint_1": "jnjn",
    "hint_2": "jknkjn"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you try replacing 
` <div className="img-wrapper">
          {this.state.countries.map(country => 
                 <img src={country.photo}/>
           )}
 </div>`
with
` <div className="img-wrapper">
        <img src={()=>{this.state.countries.photo}}/>
 </div>`

Comment: @HeroicHitesh I tried it gives the error  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: I forgot to add return statement, try this
 ` <div className="img-wrapper"> <img src={()=>{return this.state.countries.photo;}}/> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something to determine which image you want to display. In the example below, I hold, in state, the index of the current image, and then only display the image at that index:

```js
const images = [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "canada",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "sdsds",
    "capital": "sdsdsd",
    "hint_1": "sdsd",
    "hint_2": "sdsdsd"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "usa",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "ddc",
    "capital": "new york",
    "hint_1": "kuch bhi",
    "hint_2": "kljn;kj"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "china",
    "photo": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India#/media/File:Flag_of_India.svg",
    "fact": "ddfdf",
    "capital": "k k",
    "hint_1": "jnjn",
    "hint_2": "jknkjn"
  }
];

const PhotoDisplay = () => {
  const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = React.useState(0);
  
  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setCurrentImageIndex(currentImageIndex + 1);
  };
  
  const currentImage = images[currentImageIndex];
  
  console.log(currentImage);
  
  return <div>
    <button onClick={handleNextClick}>Next Image</button>
    <img src={currentImage.photo} />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <PhotoDisplay />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hey thanx man but can you please write the code in class type thnx much appreciated

Comment: @droid sorry, I can't answer questions as a coding service - if you want to convert it then you can find lots of guidance on how to do that

Comment: understandable have a great day and thnx for the help